# How do you access the child of a ControlTemplate from a parent page?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Pretty basic scenario but I could not find the solution for this, I have a page which has a ContentView, and this ContentView's ControlTemplate property changes based on a property change event using DataTrigger. Here is the code:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="view1">
        <Label x:Name="label1"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="view2">
        <Label x:Name="label2"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>


<ContentView>
    <ContentView.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger  TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource view1}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource view2}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ContentView.Triggers>
</ContentView>
```

-> How can I access "label1" and "label2" from the page ? I tried using the GetTemplateChild method but without success. Thanks for your input on this.

Edit: I did try to use GetTemplateChild on OnApplyTemplate, but OnApplyTemplate is never called. The UI of the page is correctly updated though.

Edit2: You can reproduce the issue by setting up the following page in  a MAUI project, and setting

TestPage.cs:

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _myCondition = true;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
    }
}

public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        // I put a break-point here but it is never hit.
    }
}
```

TestPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
             x:Class="TestApp.TestPage"
             >

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="view1">
            <Label Text="Hello from view 1" x:Name="label1"/>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="view2">
            <Label Text="Hello from view 2" x:Name="label2"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <ContentView>
        <ContentView.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger  TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource view1}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource view2}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </ContentView.Triggers>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetTemplateChild` method should only be called after the `OnApplyTemplate` method has been called. This is achieved by calling the [GetTemplateChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.templatedview.gettemplatechild) method from the [OnApplyTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.templatedview.onapplytemplate) override for the templated page:

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
     base.OnApplyTemplate();
     theFirstLabel = (Label)GetTemplateChild("label1");
     theSecondLabel = (Label)GetTemplateChild("label2");    
}
```

For more details, you can refer to 
[Get a named element from a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-8.0#get-a-named-element-from-a-template).

**Update:**

The key is that you need to set `ControlTemplate="{StaticResource view1}"` in your custom control. I made a working demo based on your sample.

**MyTestPage.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MyTestPage"
             Title="MyTestPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="view1">
            <Label Text="Hello from view 1" x:Name="label1"/>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="view2">
            <Label Text="Hello from view 2" x:Name="label2"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

</ContentPage>
```

**MyTestPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MyTestPage : ContentPage
{

    ControlTemplate view1;
    ControlTemplate view2;

    public MyTestPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
        view1 = (ControlTemplate)Resources["view1"];
        view2 = (ControlTemplate)Resources["view2"];
    }
}
```

**TestPage.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:MyTestPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.TestPage"
             
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource view1}"
            >


</controls:MyTestPage>
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class TestPage : MyTestPage
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
       //code to access "label1" or "label2" 
    }
}
```

After a control template has been instantiated, the `OnApplyTemplate` method is invoked. In this method we can use the `GetTemplateChild` method to access the views that compose the control like below:

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned, my bad, that OnApplyTemplate is never called.  It was my understanding that it is the way to go indeed but it seems I am missing something else.

Comment: Yes, that would work if you followed the docs. Also, you can add a minimal, reproduce sample and add it to your post so that I can help you test it.

Comment: I have added a second edit with the full code of the page. My scenario slightly differs from what is shown in the docs though I think; I am applying a template to a ContentView element present in the page, not to the whole page.

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the update which is really helpful to reproduce and resolve the issue. You can see my update.